# The JS script does not run in the project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-isotope

I put js file in assets/javascripts, it has been initialized it the project but not worked.
It only works when I connect it directly from View file with the help of `<script> </script>` tags.

*js file content*

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var iso;
  imagesLoaded( container, function() {
  iso = new Isotope( container, {
 });
});
```

Comment: Do you include this file in project?

Comment: are other files/functions in assets/javascripts working?

Comment: other files in assets are working good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code inside your document.ready:

```
  # app/assets/javascript/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function(){
 var container = document.querySelector('#container');
 var iso;
  imagesLoaded( container, function() {
  iso = new Isotope( container, {
 });
});

});
```